# how to fetch a row using id sqlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is a simple one! yet, I am missing something. Please help me out.
Here, I am trying to fetch values by id, but not able to do so. It is returning same values even after changing id's value.

```
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("DBSOURCE", 0, null);
    Cursor cursorc = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM LIST WHERE ID="+id+"", null);
    cursorc.moveToFirst();

    int NameID = cursorc.getColumnIndex("Name");
    int mobilenumberID = cursorc.getColumnIndex("MoblieNumber");

    edName.setText(cursorc.getString(NameID));
    edMobNum.setText(cursorc.getString(mobilenumberID));

    cursorc.close();

    db.close();
```

Comment: In your table, what is the type of field ID?

Comment: its of type int, its an auto incremental primary key for the table.

Comment: Write while loop to get all values from cursor

Comment: ok. But since id is a primary key , doesn't it return only one row?
anyway I am gonna try while loop now and will get back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1- 
or better to use parametrized statement

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName + " WHERE columnName = ?";
cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {comment});
```

2 - use if with conditon c.moveToFirst() or c.getCount() >0 or (!c.isAfterLast())

```
if (c.moveToFirst()){ 
    do{ 
       //if you not need the loop you can remove that
       id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
   }
 while(cursor.moveToNext());
}c.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

Is the id column title actually "ID"?  Or is that a variable that is set to "_id" (the usual column name for the primary key in an Android database)?

If the latter, your query is not right, because you are using "ID" as the literal column name.  Try changing it to this:

```
Cursor cursorc = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM LIST WHERE " + ID + " = " + id, null);
```

or even this:

```
Cursor cursorc = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM LIST WHERE _id = " + id, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
Cursor cursorc = db.rawQuery("select * from list where ID = ?", new String[] {id+""});
```

Answer (score 2):

try with this way

```
    Suppose long id=5;
    String[] col=new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_ADDRESS};  // your column which data u want to retrive if id is same 
    Cursor c=db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col, KEY_ROWID+"="+id,null, null, null, null);
    if(c!=null){
    c.moveToFirst();
    // get data here which u want accroding to ur requirement 
    }
```

Comment: have make changes accroding to ur column name supposue ur column name=_in than String KEY_ROWID="_id"  same as for database_table and other fields

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Cursor cursorc = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM LIST WHERE ID='"+id+"'", null);
```